# How can I add attributes to my app.config configuration collection?

Tags: c#, app-config

I am trying to have the following section structure in my app.config

```
<MyConfig>
    <NewsFeeds site="abc">
        <add name="first" />
    </NewsFeeds>
    <NewsFeeds site="zyx">
        <add name="another" />
    </NewsFeeds>
</MyConfig>
```

I already have the `MyConfig` section working but I am unsure of how the `NewsFeed` collection should be coded, or if this structure is even possible.  Right now I have the following classes so far:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(NewsFeedConfig))]
public class NewsFeedConfigCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new NewsFeedConfig();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((NewsFeedConfig)(element)).Name;
    }

    public NewsFeedConfig this[int idx] { get { return (NewsFeedConfig)BaseGet(idx); } }
}

public class NewsFeedConfig : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey = true, IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("source", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Source
    {
        get { return (string)base["source"]; }
        set { base["source"] = value; }
    }
}
```

However, this requires that all news feeds be under one news feed collection, and then i'd have to parse them out manually by adding a `Site` property to each element.  That's fine, but is it possible to do it in a way that the XML defined above would work?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find your answer over here: [Sections must only appear once per config file! why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768362/sections-must-only-appear-once-per-config-file-why)

You may want to restructure your xml to something more like:

```
<MyConfig>
  <NewsFeed site="abc">
    <Feeds>
      <Feed name="first" />
    </Feeds>
  </NewsFeed>
  <NewsFeed site="zyx">
    <Feeds>
      <Feed name="second" />
      <Feed name="third" />
      <Feed name="fourth" />
    </Feeds>
  </NewsFeed>
</MyConfig>
```